# What are the differences between "import dateutil.parser" and "from dateutil.parser import parse"?

Tags: python, datetime, python-dateutil

**Update:**

I am sorry for my careless, mixing up the word `parse` and `parser`. This question should be deleted. But since someone answered it and received reputations, I kept it here. Sorry again.

---

What are the differences between (`import dateutil.parser`)

```
>>> import dateutil.parser
>>> t = dateutil.parser.parser("2012-01-19 17:21:00 BRST")
>>> type(t)
<class 'dateutil.parser.parser'>
```

and (`from dateutil.parser import parse`)

```
>>> from dateutil.parser import parse
>>> t = parse("2012-01-19 17:21:00 BRST")
>>> type(t)
<type 'datetime.datetime'>
```

Can anyone explain the differences between `import dateutil.parser` and `from dateutil.parser import parse`?

Comment: you're not calling the same function ...

Comment: @MMF, thx for pointing out this. sorry for my carefuless.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you are actually calling the constructor for the `parser` object, not the `parse` method. You can either call `dateutil.parser.parse` or instantiate a `dateutil.parser.parser` object and call its `parse()` method.

```
>>> import dateutil.parser
>>> t = dateutil.parser.parse("2012-01-19 17:21:00 BRST")
>>> type(t)
datetime.datetime
>>> t
datetime.datetime(2012, 1, 19, 17, 21)
```

Generally you can construct a `parser` object with a `dateutil.parser.parserinfo` object, but since you're not actually *using* the `parser` object, it's not throwing an error when it detects that you've passed it a string instead.